# rivets.js: prepopulate model with data from view on init

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, rivets.js

Perhaps this seems a bit backwards, but I have a view bound with Rivets.js for which I'd like the view to populate the model on initialization.

The usecase is that I'm using server-side rendering to return a snippet (the view) including rivets' data-attributes. So NO JSON is returned from server to client.

Now, by pressing 'edit' a user may put the content in 'edit'-mode, and start editing at will. (Using contenteditable, but this is out of scope here I guess).

So how to make sure the model is populated with values from the view on init?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is a little outdated but I recentry tried rivets and I came across the same problem.

The solution:

```
// In your rivets configuration you disable preload:
rivets.configure({
  templateDelimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  preloadData: false
});

// you bind your data
var binding = rivets.bind($('#auction'), {auction: auction});

// you manually publish it once to populate your model with form's data
binding.publish();
```

And that's it. I still don't know how to disable prelaod per bind

Comment: You can override configurations for a particular view by passing a third parameter to `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

From the example on Rivets website (assign to 'rivetBinding')

```
var view = rivets.bind($('#auction'), {auction: auction});
```

doing `rivetBinding.publish();` will bootstrap the model with values from the view for all bindings that have 'publishes = true'.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `var rivetBinding = rivets.bind($('#auction'), {auction: auction});`? Or where does `rivetBinding` come from?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but it still has no accepted answer, so here goes:

You need to disable the preload configuration so rivets doesn't override whatever is in the input with what you have in your model at the time you do the binding. This can be done via the `preloadData=false` configuration, either globally (`rivets.configure(...)`) or view-scoped (third param to `rivets.bind(...)`).

After the binding, you need to publish the view (pull the values to your model). You also need to set up the observers via `sync()` call, otherwise your binded methods won't be triggered.

Using the same example as the previous answers:

```
var view = rivets.bind($('#auction'), { auction: auction }, {
  preloadData: false
});

view.publish();
view.sync();
```